# switchMap operation only running on first call?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an angular application that makes a request to an Http service and calls a switchMap on another Http service. For some reason the request in the switchMap only runs the first time the parent call is called. Otherwise the parent request fires and the switchMap one doesn't, here is the code:

```
this._receivableService.newTenantDebitCredit(tenantCredit)
            .take(1)
            .switchMap(result =>
                // Refresh the lease receivables before giving result
                this._receivableService.getAll({
                    refresh: true,
                    where: { leaseId: this.leaseId }
                }).take(1).map(() => result)
            )
            .subscribe(
                ...
            )
```

How can I make the getAll request in the switch map run every time the newTenantDebitCredit method is called above it?

Edit: Here is the entirety of the function that is called on `click`. when i click the button the first time for a given unit both methods are executed. If I try a Unit that has already had that method called (without a refresh) only the first method is executed. I realize a lot of this may not be clear it's a rather large project at this point.

```
public submitTenantCredit() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        let tenantCredit: NewTenantDebitCreditData;
        let receivableDefinitions: ReceivableDefinition[] = [];

        // construct receivable defintions for NewTenantDebitData model
        receivableDefinitions = this._constructReceivableDefinitions();

        // construct data we will be POSTing to server.
        tenantCredit = new NewTenantDebitCreditData({
            siteId: this._apiConfig.siteId,
            leaseId: this.leaseId,
            isCredit: true,
            receivables: receivableDefinitions,
            reason: this.actionReason
        });

        // make service call and handle response
        this._receivableService.newTenantDebitCredit(tenantCredit)
            .take(1)
            .switchMap(result =>
                // Refresh the lease receivables before giving result
                this._receivableService.getAll({
                    refresh: true,
                    where: { leaseId: this.leaseId }
                }).take(1).map(() => result)
        )
            .take(1)
            .subscribe(
                (receivables) => {
                    this.closeReasonModal();
                    let refreshLeaseId = this.leaseId;
                    this.leaseId = refreshLeaseId;
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    this.refreshBool = !this.refreshBool;
                    this._debitCreditService.refreshUnitInfo();
                    this._notifications.success(`The tenant credit for ${this.customerName} - Unit ${this.unitNumber} was submitted successfully`);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                    this.isLoading = false;
                }
            )
    }
```

If it helps `newTenantDebitCredit(`) is a `HTTP POST` request and `getAll()` is a `GET` request.

Comment: May be try wrapping the `getAll` in an `Observable.defer`? Docs http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html

Comment: defer just froze the request.

Comment: can u provide code for this._receivableService.newTenantDebitCredit

Comment: @Zachscs As @FanCheung pointed out, please also provide what `ReceivableService` looks like; at least the two methods used here.

Comment: Receivable service extends the base API service which has its own definitions. This might not be a good questions for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer but I did solve my problem. It will almost certainly be of no use to anyone BUT it was an issue in the receivableService it was not properly cheeking the `boolean`: `refresh` and was pulling values from cache after the first time.

Answer (score 4):

You used take operator. When your service observable will emit then take operator will execute first and take will chain only first emit from observable. Subsequent emit will not taken by your code. 
If you want to take all emits from observable then remove take from your code.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I removed both take statements and it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use mergeMap instead of switchMap?  For mergeMap, no subscription will be canceled.

Comment: @SamuelShyu do you mean with removing take as well? Which take operators need to be removed? removing all and using mergemap does not solve the issue.

Comment: How could anyone upvote this when I clearly said it had no effect on the issue...

Comment: Is a cold request that emits 1 and completes so take(1) has no effect. Removing it would not solve the problem. downvote

Answer (score 3):

Testing the Rx code in isolation, here's a mockup. The console logs happen each time, so I think the Rx you're using is ok.

The best guess at a likely culprit is `this.refreshBool = !this.refreshBool`, but we'd need to see the internals of `newTenantDebitCredit` and `getAll` to be definitive.

```js
// Some mocking
const _receivableService = {
  newTenantDebitCredit: (tc) => {
    console.log('inside newTenantDebitCredit')
    return Rx.Observable.of({prop1:'someValue'})
  },
  getAll: (options) => {
    console.log('inside getAll')
    return Rx.Observable.of({prop2:'anotherValue'})
  }
}
const tenantCredit = {}

// Test
_receivableService.newTenantDebitCredit(tenantCredit)
  .take(1)
  .switchMap(result => {
    console.log('result', result)
    return _receivableService.getAll({ 
      refresh: true,
      where: { leaseId: this.leaseId }
    })
    .take(1)
    .map(() => result)
  })
  .take(1)
  .subscribe(
    (receivables) => {
      console.log('receivables', receivables)
      //this.refreshBool = !this.refreshBool;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    }
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think the third take 1 is unnecessary, in the switchMap you subscribe to the returned Observable which already uses the take operator. It can only emit one value and than complete.

Comment: I just copied @Zachscs code verbatum, as I just wanted to see if the Rx was working - which it is.

Comment: Certainly there's some bits I would write differently, but the point of the post is to show that the `switchMap()` fires both observerables each time the button is clicked.

Comment: So, now I need to see more code to progress any further. I'm hoping @Zachscs will oblige, otherwise he may have wasted his bounty points.

Comment: Ah ok now I get it, sorry. 
Yes I think the service would give more insight. In most cases of "getAll" / "getMultiple" operations I like to use forkjoin.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I gave you the bounty points because it seems like you put in the most effort and insight. I'll post more code today if you can help further I'll select your answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this has nothing to do with the `switchMap` operator.

Normaly removing the `take(1)` would cause this behaviour. In this case it wouldn't because it itsn't a so called hot observable.

The problem is that you are using a `http.post`. This is a cold observable which means it will only return a value once. That is also the reason why you don't need to unsubscribe. It will NEVER fire twice. Possible sollutions might be:

1. Using web sockets to get realtime data.
2. Creating a timer which will periodically fetch the data.
3. Simply get the data again whenever you need it.

Comment: So the first request is a post request and it is triggered by a click event. This is fired every time. The get request that is switchMapped to the post is the one that only fires once.

Comment: Can you add the methods for the requests?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are asking the question

> How can I make the getAll request in the switch map run every time the newTenantDebitCredit method is called above it?

actually sounds to me as if you are calling *only* `newTenantDebitCredit` from somewhere in your code, expecting the second request to happen; so I think this might be a misunderstanding of how observable chains work. Let's make an example:

```
const source$ = Observable.of(42);
source$
  .map(value => 2 * value)
  .subscribe(console.log);
source$
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

What would you expect this to log? If your answer is "It would log 84 twice", then that is wrong: it logs 84 and 42.

Conceptually, your situation is the same. The second request only happens when the observable returned by `newTenantDebitCredit()` *emits*; it will not happen anytime some caller calls `newTenantDebitCredit`. This is because observable chains do not mutate an observable in-place, they only ever return a *new* observable.

---

If you want the second request to happen, you have to actually change the definition of the `newTenantDebitCredit` method to return an observable set up to perform the second request; alternatively, set up a chained observable that you subscribe to instead of calling `newTenantDebitCredit`.

Comment: But the second request happens the first time?

Comment: Also I'm calling a method where the code above is the content. So that switchMap is always a part of `newTenantDebitCredit()`

Comment: @Zachscs I could explain why the second request is called once, but if you actually call that entire chain each time, my explanation is void. However, I think it's time you showed a more complete scenario of your code: what the involved methods look like and also what and how you are calling.

Comment: I posted the entire function, still might not be clear what is going on.